# How can I make a case to be moved back to my preferred shift?

Tags: united-states, human-resources, manager

When I started this contract, I was working 4 ten hour days Mon-Thur on swing shift.

Then I got hired full time and was essentially forced to work three 12 hour days Fri-Sun or I'd lose my job.

Is there any way to skillfully demonstrate why I need to be moved back onto the Mon-Thur shift besides pointing out how project work is better completed when I can network with resources during the business week?

-edits:

This is a 24/7 Operations Center.  Think network support and other business functions.  I work in Information Technology.

When I say I was forced, I mean precisely that.  Either switch or leave.

Its been less than 6 months since the switch.

My second sentence (probably should be on a new line) explains I went full time from being a contractor.

Comment: If you were "forced" to swap shifts then there's arguably not much you can do. Could you clarify what you mean by that, how long it's been since the change in shifts, and whether you're hired as a consultant (as your reference to a contract seems to imply)? (Tagged US based on your profile)

Comment: Great feedback everyone, I'll edit the question to provide more details.  I wanted to keep things as vague as possible to avoid the off-chance someone within the company would come across this.

Comment: One more update, as far as I have been able to learn by asking around, I am set in stone on this shift.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any way to skillfully demonstrate why I need to be moved back
>   onto the Mon-Thur shift

You are better off focusing on your personal needs and hoping that they are willing to meet your needs, rather than risk losing you.

Based on your recent edit, there is clearly a compelling need from a business point of view that makes it important for the company to have some good folks working the Fri-Sun shift (or else they wouldn't "force" people to do so). They have thought this through and decided that this shift is an effective way to cover those hours. I suspect you cannot argue that nobody should cover this shift. Thus, "pointing out how project work is better completed when I can network with resources during the business week" is almost certainly a waste of time. Instead you should argue that *you* shouldn't be forced to cover this shift.

Talk about how it affects you, and see if they can switch you back to your old shift.

That said, it's possible that everyone else on the shift feels like you do, and that the newbies get the least favored shift, while the old-timers get preferred shifts. If that's the case, you may just need to wait your turn.

Comment: This is probably exactly right. Old joke, but everyone has to take their turn in the barrel. But it has been almost 6 months, probably someone else's turn.

Comment: Just to revisit this, I've vocalized my concerns with working the Fri-Sun shift and got stonewalled.  Meaning I cannot change shifts unless there is an opening.  From talking to other shift co-workers, the majority enjoy the shift and specifically volunteered for it.  Personally speaking I have only been a contract worker so becoming an employee is new to me.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I have been looking around since December.  Also, I don't want to let the last year be tossed aside.  So I really am in a difficult spot.  I really appreciate the replies.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to skillfully demonstrate why I need to be moved back
>   onto the Mon-Thur shift besides pointing out how project work is
>   better completed when I can network with resources during the business
>   week?

First brainstorm

1. How does this benefit the team, the organization
2. How does it benefit you, so the result is that is benefits the team, the organization

I'd create a free-hand flowchart with text in bubbles, with arrows pointing to one another.

Then, organize your thoughts on paper, in a format that you can hand over to whoever is in charge of your timing (if it is necessary, depends on your situation)

Finally, call a meeting with the person to discuss. Be heart-full about how the change will help you help them.

Because on weekday you are more productive since you have resources around you.

If the Management is good, they will accommodate and understand the benefits to their organization of restructuring your time, else, you must search for job elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I used to manage a group of engineers exactly like your group.  About 40 guys on four different levels and my job was manage everything NOT 9-5 Mon-Fri.

The shift they put you on is thought of as a nightmare by 80-90% of the population given that loved ones usually are not working on the weekends.  And I also know that if you work those shifts on the weekend that your other weekend time is basically sleeping.

But the other 10-20% of the population absolutely LOVES that shift.  You work 3 damn days a week and can do whatever you want for most of your week.

So the guys who worked for me that were successful at getting off their weekend shift came up and told me.  I asked the others in the group if they wanted to switch.

The smart people sold their shift to the others.  You could even sell it to people who aren't on your team that have the skills.... so sounds great right?

Well... the Mon.-Thurs. x10 shift was actually something I started at my company to help retention.  This only went to my best and most tenured guys.  I had guys stay on this shift and pass over promotion after promotion that would have made them go 9-5 x5.

So your best bet is to see if you can get someone to switch with you.  Even going to your manager may not even be the best thing.  If someone came to me and said this surely the other weekenders might hear and if they have more tenure than you or if I think they are better, I would let them switch first.  But if you came to me with a 1 for 1 switch I would probably OK it given like positions.

In the end you got a permanent job.  You are low man on the pole, probably asking for a premium position.  You are also working a shift with little to no social game interaction with decision makers...  If this is a deal breaker for you I would start looking elsewhere.

Comment: The companies decision to put me on this shift might have been due to some improvement work I started doing.  Putting the resource the closest to the problem in an effort to solve it.  I disagree with that world view.  I've been waiting for the right time to re-dress this topic with the management.

Comment: Well if you aren't covering a "shift" and were just asked to work those days to help whatever you are doing that is different.  I was answering the question based on that shift needing coverage.

Comment: To loop back to this, the company allocated my skills by assigning me the shift where the company believed I'd do the most good. I again vocalize that I disagree, as such I walked out after failing to secure a promotion to another team.